# Installing GCC on Oracle Solaris 11

Tags: oracle, gcc, solaris

i recently got Oracle Solaris on my VM to test some code on it, i was unable to install gcc since i dont really know how, i googled alot but all info is about oracle compilers, i needed GCC, any idea where can i get GCC or how to install it?

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The original answer applied to Solaris 11 Express/non-official release - if you're doing this today with a full release of Solaris 11.x, use the `pkg install` command like you see in [xavier's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13527976/297696) response.**

Run this command from your terminal to install GCC.

For GCC 3.4.x

```
pkg install gcc-3
```

For GCC 4.5.x

```
pkg install gcc-45
```

For GCC 4.7.x

```
pkg install gcc-47
```

For GCC 4.8.x

```
pkg install gcc-48
```

The `gcc` command should then already be placed in your path `/usr/bin/gcc`, which is a symlink).

---

***Old Answer***
Solaris 11 should already have gcc installed in `/usr/sfw/bin/`, but it's probably not in your `PATH`. Try this at the prompt: `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc`

Comment: no, its not there, i checked, and just checked again, i also ran a find command

Comment: `sudo pkg install gcc-3` then to install the package.   `pkg search gcc` could have found that package name for you.

Comment: ty, it worked :), but just 1 qustion, its version 3.4 from 2005, no newer versions?

Comment: @killercode - sorry I didn't respond sooner - no, the official package is just GCC 3.4.x. When I did software ports on Solaris, a client requested GCC 4.4, which meant I had to build my own GCC 4.4 with the GCC 3.4 provided.

Comment: The actual Solaris 11 release (November 2011) now has both 3.4.3 and 4.5.2.   The Solaris 11 Express preview from November 2010 only had the older 3.4.3.

Comment: Blast from the past. I'm now back in Solaris land and I am using pkgutil to make life easier: http://pkgutil.net/

Comment: I did have to install the compiler, but no need to change my PATH variable.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (but may have been correct if it was written for a *pre-release* of Solaris 11 back then, dunno ?). Anyways:  `gcc` on Solaris 11 doesn't live in `/usr/sfw/bin`. You are confusing with Solaris 10.

Comment: @peterh At the time this question was posed, Solaris 11 wasn't out yet, only Solaris 11 Express or some prerelease I had access to, which was basically Solaris 10 with some intermediate transition features.

Answer (score 16):

Two steps:

1. pkg install gcc-45
2. pkg install system/header

that is all

if you see more info
http://blog.csdn.net/zjg555543/article/details/8217769

Comment: `pkg install gcc-45` also installs `system/header` so no need for the 2nd command.

Comment: I did not get `system/header` on OpenIndiana with the first command, so I warmly thank you for the second command.

Answer (score 3):

Just download gcc from its homepage, follow one of the mirror links to fetch the latest binary package (in .tar.gz or tar.bz2 format), and use traditional steps to build:

1. ./configure --<>  // give your options
2. make
3. make install

The good news is you can customize what you need and always stay with the latest, while bad part is you may lose the power to debug with mdb/adb - we are facing such problems with latest GCC 4.6.x

Comment: @AlexisWilke Our solaris box was shipped with a default GCC in /usr/sfw/bin, which can be used to build something at least.

Comment: Interesting. I installed Solaris from CD in a virtual box and the /usr/sfw directory did not exist. birryree mentioned that directory too in his answer... but I could not see it and still cannot see it!

Comment: alexis - gcc has been buildable without a compiler since the mid 90's.  it's slow, and involved.  any good compiler can be boostrapped from lower level tools (bison, yacc, ar, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Solaris 10 and prior version :

/usr/sfw/bin/gcc works.

Solaris 11 :

pkg install gcc-3

Answer (score 2):

```
pkg install gcc
```

worked for me

This will install entire gcc collection on your machine. Which anyways will be required

Answer (score 2):

My Solaris 2.11 **does NOT have internet access** :/

**What work for me:**

(1) I use [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) as guideline
(2) From my windows machine, download gcc at one of their [mirror sites](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), i used [here](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/gcc/releases/gcc-9.2.0/), normally the closer the better
(3) Upload gcc-9.2.0.tar.gz to target */tmp* directory using WinSCP
(4) tar -xvf gcc-9.2.0.tar.gz
(5) cd gcc-9.2.0
(6) mkdir /usr/local/gcc
(7) cd /usr/local/gcc
(8) /tmp/gcc-9.2.0/configure -v --program-suffix=9.2

At this point, you might get this error:
 **Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.**

(9) Manually download the required files [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/).
Note: To know what files are required, check **contrib/download_prerequisites**
(10)Copy over the files in (9) to /tmp/gcc-9.2.0
(11)Extract, then create shortcuts: ln -s gmp-6.1.0 gmp, ln -s mpc-1.0.3 mpc, ln -s mpfr-3.1.4 mpfr, ln -s isl-0.18 isl
(12)/tmp/gcc-9.2.0/configure -v --program-suffix=9.2 --enable-languages=c,c++ -v
(13) nohup gmake & (At this point it's going to take some time...mine took ~6 hours. Use -j option if you can, to gmake it faster )
(14) gmake install
(15) /usr/local/bin# ./gcc9.2 --version
gcc9.2 (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

**Voila! :-)**

Answer (score 1):

You can install gcc 4.3 from OpenCSW:

```
pkg-get -i gcc4code gcc4g++
```

I also had to run mkheaders manually after the install.

Comment: gcc-4.6.2 is now available from the unstable catalog.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and 'pkg install gcc-3' worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll quote the answer from [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/solaris-development-host).

On Solaris 11 `gcc` is not installed by default. Normally you'll want more than just the compiler itself so my answer will include **all** the usual suspects for building open source software on Solaris that you've downloaded from somewhere in source code format.

By far the easiest is to use IPS to install it using the commands below (while being root or other superuser):

```
pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/build/gnu-make \
            pkg://solaris/developer/build/make \
            pkg://solaris/developer/gcc \
            pkg://solaris/system/header \
            pkg://solaris/developer/build/autoconf \
            pkg://solaris/developer/build/automake
```

(I use fully qualified package names here, that is not really necessary)

Note that some of the packages are available in the official repo in various versions. If you just reference `developer/gcc` then you'll at the time of writing this get GNU C v4.8.2, but you may explicitly ask for a prior version, e.g. by using package name such as `developer/gcc-45`.