# Install GNU c/c++ in solaris 11 with Solaris Studio

Tags: c++, compilation

I need to install GNU c/c++ in solaris 11. The box provided is a solaris zone. I don't have the sudo permission as well as root for the zone does not have the privilege for using pkg command.

Solaris 11 does not come with default gcc.

Solaris studio has been provided with the gnu c/c++ source code.

How can I install gcu c/c++ with the help of Solaris Studio.

Please help on this, thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anand Kumar Keshri

Comment: Did you check in `/usr/sfw/bin` for `gcc` and `g++`?

Comment: Yes I checked the /usr/sfw/bin. I tried find command also.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can tell how can I compile gcc with the help of solaris studio.

Comment: I've done this before several times, and it's an extremely error-prone and excruciating process if you can't install binaries and must build using SunCC. What version of Solaris studio are you running? Why do you need GCC over SunCC? Do you have any of the GCC build dependencies ready? (gmake 3.80+, GMP, mpfr,  mpc). This is not a simple answer.

Comment: I was spiking on the internet for the feasibility of installing gnu c/c++ with the help of studio.. Whether it is possible or not ? Thanks  for your answer.. that it is possible. And you have done it several times... As i don't have the permission to use pkg install gcc-3 from the zone... I was looking for this path

Comment: I'll attempt to write an answer in the morning when I am clear-headed enough to write down steps to do Solaris stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing GCC on Oracle Solaris 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664472/installing-gcc-on-oracle-solaris-11)

Answer (score 0):

You may just build it from the sources, and install gcc in some place, where you have permissions to do so, i.e.,

```
./configure --prefix=${HOME}/gcc
make
make install
export PATH=${HOME}/gcc:${PATH}
```

Comment: I can't do this because it also requires gcc to compile gcc. As I mentioned there is no default gcc available.

Comment: Oh if it were really only this simple - when you're on the Solaris toolchain there is a lot more to consider (like using the GNU `ld` vs. Sun `ld` - pick the latter), and in his environment he's going to probably have to build a ton of dependencies himself.

Comment: There is a way to build gcc from source, starting with a non-gcc compiler.  The process uses the native compiler to build an intermediate gcc executable, then uses that to build the final gcc.  I've done it, but not in several years, and the details have probably changed with later gcc releases.  I do remember that one of the steps was `make bootstrap`.  And as others have mentioned, setting up the prerequisites is non-trivial.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Last time I did this was in 2010 - the process is still like that depending on your starting point. Bootstrap GCC, hope it builds with SunCC (or compiler of choice), and if that works, you can then use that GCC to rebuild the dependencies again and rebuild GCC.

Comment: I think it should be: export PATH=${HOME}/gcc/bin:${PATH} (you need the .../bin part).

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an answer to your question, but you can get a Solaris package of gcc from http://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWgcc4core/

(I have built gcc using a non-gcc C compiler to start with, but not for many years.)