# Cannot install Date::Calc perl module

Tags: perl, solaris

I'm running Solaris on my machine and I would need to install the Date::Calc perl module in order for one of my scripts to work.

When I run the following command:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Date::Calc'
```

I get the following error:

```
Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (Bit::Vector)
  STBEY/Date-Calc-6.3.tar.gz
  [dependencies] -- NA
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I have no prior experience in Perl development, so I have no clue about what the error might be or where to get more information.

What should I do to fix this?

---

When trying to install Bit::Vector first, i.e. when running the following command:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bit::Vector'
```

i get the following error message:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Bit::Vector
Writing patchlevel.h for /usr/bin/perl (5.012003)
cp lib/Bit/Vector/Overload.pm blib/lib/Bit/Vector/Overload.pm
cp Vector.pm blib/lib/Bit/Vector.pm
cp Vector.pod blib/lib/Bit/Vector.pod
cp lib/Bit/Vector/Overload.pod blib/lib/Bit/Vector/Overload.pod
cp lib/Bit/Vector/String.pod blib/lib/Bit/Vector/String.pod
cp lib/Bit/Vector/String.pm blib/lib/Bit/Vector/String.pm
cc -c    -DPTR_IS_LONG -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -xO4    -DVERSION=\"7.2\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"7.2\" -KPIC "-I/usr/perl5/5.12/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/CORE"   BitVector.c
sh: line 1: cc: not found
*** Error code 127
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `BitVector.o'
  STBEY/Bit-Vector-7.2.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

---

I installed gcc via the following commands (as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13527976/1103412)):

```
pkg install gcc-45 
pkg install system/header
```

but I still get the same error when trying to install Bit::Vector. Indeed, when I type `cc` on the command-line, I get the `command not found` error. When I type `gcc`, however, I get `gcc: no input files`.

Comment: `Data::Calc` depends on `Bit::Vector` . the command you have run should have installed `Bit::Vector` automatically with no issues. But in your case it is failing. Try installing `Bit::Vector` and later install `Data::Calc`

Comment: check: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/bin-sh-cc-command-not-found-641293/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the only option is to install the [Oracle Solaris Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html) prior to installation of new perl modules which need to compile C code.

From [a related discussion at Oracle Solaris forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2540821&stqc=true):

> CC modification in /usr/perl5/5.12/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int/Config.pm
>   will not resolve the compilation issue. New errors will be produced
>   and some part will not use this variable.
>
> By default, this method to build modules will use perl compiled
>   options. And in this case, as we used Oracle Studio, this software
>   will be required because some options are not available with gcc.
>
> I tried with Oracle Studio, and the compilation was done successfully.
>
> If you want to use gcc, then this will be very tricky to modify
>   several perl config files. An another method is to compile manually
>   each necessary modules after you customize each Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that [Bit::Vector](https://metacpan.org/module/Bit%3a%3aVector) (a dependency of Date::Calc) failed to install for some reason. Bit::Vector requires compiling C code, which means your CPAN configuration will need access to the C compiler and libraries (and headers) that were used to build your perl.

From what I understand, that can sometimes be painful on Solaris.

If you have another C compiler available, you might consider building and installing a local Perl using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

Comment: it used to need a workaround (Solaris::PerlGcc) to compile modules with a free compiler when the system perl wasn't, but that's in the fairly distant past; I suspect the issue here is just not having a compiler at all, a problem that isn't unique to Solaris