# Installing .tar packages on Solaris 11.1

Tags: unix, gcc, solaris

I'm not the first to say this but I'm new to Unix OS and have chosen to learn Solaris to start. Currently I have Solaris v11 installed on a i86p system that is standalone (no web access)

The goal was to install Wire-shark but after I extracted the .tar file and ran ./configure it was noted that it failed because no C compiler was found. Turns out from what I've [read](http://everythingsolaris.org/articles/iaug/frameset.html) Solaris by default does not come with a C compiler and it was recommended that gcc be installed. Downloaded the .tar, extracted it in the /tmp directory and following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664472/installing-gcc-on-oracle-solaris-11) steps; noted during the ./configure that it also was looking for a C complier which I do not have. This prevents me from performing the next step (make). I'm a bit lost on how to overcome this paradox. Also for my own understanding am I correct with the following:

1. ./configure: checks system for necessary dependencies and creates MAKEFILE
2. make: actually makes the binary
3. make install: installs the application appropriately for use

Also please note as stated earlier this is a standalone device not connected to a network. It seems that such options as `pkg install gcc-45`(getting and installing directly from Oracle) is the easiest but this I do think is a worth wild exercise to understand.

Comment: Is there a reason you picked `solaris`? It's not one of the main OS's used. I would check out some Linux flavor instead like Ubuntu...

Comment: Solaris should have the `cc` compiler. What the output of `which cc` ?

Comment: which cc produced "cc not found"

Comment: I guess I would also ask if a negative rating is to be left constructive feedback as to what I can do to improve would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Ekendahl: Solaris was picked because many of the servers we have are running a flavor of it. I guess I see Ubuntu as more of a client OS, could be very wrong.

Comment: @RobertEkendahl Solaris is indeed not the main OS used, especially in the desktop market, but has recently regained the #1 rank in the commercial Unix server market https://blogs.oracle.com/partnertech/entry/oracle_regains_the_1_unix

Comment: Tip: I use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for running Solaris 11 inside my Win7 laptop. Runs perfectly. This way I have web access too. I run a single Solaris image and within that I have a 9 different hosts, complete with virtualized network (routers, switches), firewalls and what have you. I do this to match a real-world (physical) environment that we have at work. I run all that on a standard Win7 laptop with 8Gb RAM and concurrently running lots of Win apps as well. I can't do such a low-key, low-cost, 100% matching replica with any other OS I know of.

Comment: I'm curious since this is a production environment general thoughts on CentOS? I do like the Ubuntu community but the feeling I'm getting is platforms like Solaris and CentOS provide more stability than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `wireshark` and `gcc` are standard Solaris 11 packages. The link you posted that states otherwise is outdated, being 13 years old and anyway related to Solaris 8 and older.

If you have no Internet connection on your Solaris machine, you can nevertheless download the whole Solaris 11 repository from the same location where you download the media you already used ( Look for "Oracle Solaris 11.1 Repository Image" in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html ) then install both of these package from a local repository.

The simple procedure to follow is described in a `README` file contained in the iso.

Once done, you can simply install `wireshark` and `gcc` with:

```
pkg install wireshark gcc-45
```

By the way, you might have a look to Solaris 11.2 beta which has some interesting new features, including kernel zones and OpenStack support.

Comment: Thank you jlliagre for the suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. The usual way to thank answerers on stackexchange sites is to vote up or accept an answer (or both).

Comment: I do appreciate the input and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (it seems) is to `build` packages from source. This is a more complex way then using a package manager and to do that you will need a C compiler to `build` with. Without an installed C compiler you cannot build other packages. So you need to find a way to install (from the install DVD?) compilers etc. if you want to build other packages.

I would recommend you find a way to install wire-shark from a package manager instead..

Hope this helps...