# Install gcc on Solaris 11 error read-only filesystem

Tags: gcc, solaris, openindiana

I downloaded oracle VM virtual box and the openindiana distribution of solaris.  I tired to run gcc but it said "command not found".

I found instructions for installing gcc here [Installing GCC on Oracle Solaris 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664472/installing-gcc-on-oracle-solaris-11) but when I run something like pkg install gcc-3 it gives the message:

pkg install: Could not complete the operation on /var/pkg/lock: read-only filesystem.

Can anyone tell me how I can get gcc running on this setup?

Comment: You ran `pkg install gcc-3` as root, or used `sudo`?  Alternatively, are you running in a zone?  Or booting off a CD/DVD image?

Comment: I used sudo and received the above message.  I don't know if I'm running in a zone, how would I check.  I just opened the terminal and typed the command in.

Comment: Did you go through an install process into your VM?  From what you've posted, it looks like you're running openindiana on a Virtual Box VM.  If you didn't go through an installation process, you're probably running off the CD/DVD image, which would explain the "read-only file system" error.  The install process appears to be here:  http://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/Installing+OpenIndiana

Comment: This was the problem, I was still running from the disk image.  Thank you so much!